# Laravel Route error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Well,  I have this error: 'Route [setor] not defined' when calling my view, but my route is configured.

```
Route::resource('empresa', 'EmpresaController');
Route::resource('setor', 'SetorController');
Route::resource('departamento', 'DepartamentoController');
Route::resource('funcionario', 'FuncionarioController');
```

And my Controller code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Setor;

class SetorController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $setores = Setor::all();
        return view('indicador.setor.index', compact('setores'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('indicador.setor.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $setor = Setor::create($request->all());
        return redirect('setor');
    }
```

There are other objects configured equal this and executing.

And my view:

```
    @extends('template.principal')

@section('pageName')

    <h1>Setor</h1>

@endsection

@section('content')

    <table class="table">    

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 hero-feature">    
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Setor</th>
                <th>Empresa</th>    
            </tr>
            </thead>
            @foreach($setores as $setor)
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $setor->nome }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $setor->id_empresa }}</td>
                    <td><a href="{{ action('SetorController@show', $setor) }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a></td>
                    <td><a href="{{ action('SetorController@edit', $setor) }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></td>    
                </tr>
                </tbody>
        @endforeach

        <!--<button href="{{ route('setor.create') }}" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Adicionar</button>-->
            <button type="button" onclick="window.location='{{ route("setor") }}'">Adicinar</button>

        </div>    
    </table>    
@endsection
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post more of your routes file or your controller?

Comment: No problem, i did put the informations

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: Can you do php artisan route:list? Also, what happens if you create Route::get('setor', 'SetorController@index');?

Comment: should be setor.index. check php artisan route:list

Answer (score 2):

Per [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers), `Route::resource` generates *several* routes.

`Route::resource('setor', 'SetorController');` will generate the following named routes:

- `setor.index`
- `setor.create`
- `setor.store`
- `setor.show`
- `setor.edit`
- `setor.update`
- `setor.destroy`

It will **not** create a route called `setor`, which is why you have the error when you do `{{ route("setor") }}`. Pick the appropriate one from the list.

You can view the full list of configured routes with their names (if applicable) using `php artisan route:list`.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you added a new Route File, Make sure it is referenced in `mapWebRoutes()` method inside

> app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php

2. You could also run following command to check your registered routes

   php artisan route:list
3. You could clear Route cache by using below command and then retry

   php artisan route:clear

Hope this will be useful for you.

Answer (score -2):

In my case this issue occurred after downloading project from GitHub.
Also I reinstalled "PHP Intelephense" from from VS Code.

Comment: You've assumed they're using Github, VS Code, and Intelephense. None of these appear to be stated in the question, and the error they're getting has nothing to do with them.

Comment: Intelephense has nothing to do with the Named Routes that are generated via `Route::resource(...)`... With or without Intelephense, using `return redirect('setor');` in combination with `Route::resource('setor', 'SetorController');` would still trigger that error. *"Do yo have any solutions"* - ceejayoz posted the correct solution above, which is to use `route('setor.index')`. *"Or you just fart with your mouth!"* - This kind of statement is a great way to get yourself banned from participating on Stackoverflow...

Comment: Hey idiots I just shared my experience. From the beginning  I was saying in my case!